# Sync accounts with different SO/SE profile (not the oldest)

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

There seems to be no answer to this already. Every time I create a new SE account, it fills in the new account's data with the data from the "*oldest*" profile (which is something I don't want), so I have to change it every single time (username, info, etc). How can I change which account is used to "`sync`" with (and especially, to pull the data from when creating a new account)?